# Expected Winnings

Tags: probability

https://webwork.math.nau.edu/webwork2_files/tmp/MLanzetta_114_A//gif/rau7-3409-setWebwork_4prob8image1.png

Consider the following game of chance based on the spinner below:
Each spin costs \$3. If the spinner lands on C the player wins \$9, if the spinner stops on D the player wins a dime otherwise the player wins nothing. Calculate the players expected winnings. Express your answer to at least three decimal places in dollar form. .
$\text{       }$

I came up with -0.241 but I know that is wrong, were am I off?

Comment: Can you explain how you got $-0.241$?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is from webwork, you should tag it (or any assignments) with Homework.

The definition for expectation gives you

$$\text{Expected Payout} = (\$0)\cdot P(A)+(\$0)\cdot P(B)+(\$9)\cdot P(C)+(\$0.10)\cdot P(D)  $$

But you're in the hole $\$3$, so add $-3$ to the above.